# I have a nav in an unordered list. On hover these images are supposed to switch out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onmouseout

The whole page is a PHP include inside of a main index file.  Should I be placing the javascript on the main page? or an external javascript file?  Am I referencing the li wrong?

```
<ul>
<li class="about"><a href="index.php?about"><h1>about</h1></a></li>
<li class="team"><a href="index.php?team"><h1>team</h1></a></li>
<li class="training"><a href="index.php?training"><h1>training </h1></a></li>
<li class="courses"><a href="index.php?courses"><h1>courses</h1></a></li>
<li class="register"><a href="index.php?contact"><h1>contact</h1></a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("div").hover(
function () {
$(this).addClass("navhover");
},
function () {
$(this).removeClass("navhover");
}
); 
</script>
```

(external CSS page)

```
<script type="text/css">
#center .navhover {
   background:  url(images/active.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
}

#center .about {
 background: url(../images/about.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: It's invalid HTML to have a `h1` element inside an `a` element like that. Also `h1` is for headlines not for menu items.

Comment: Any special reason you are using jQuery/JavaScript for hovering rather that CSS?

Comment: @RoToRa In HTML5 you can have an <a> element around a <h1> element but you're right that there shouldn't be a list of h1's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just skip the javascript and use

```
li.about {
    background: url(../images/about.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}

li.about:hover {
    background:  url(images/active.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("ul li").hover(function () {
          $(this).addClass("navhover");
        },function () {
          $(this).removeClass("navhover");
        }
    ); 
});

</script>
<ul>
<li class="about"><a href="index.php?about"><h1>about</h1></a></li>
<li class="team"><a href="index.php?team"><h1>team</h1></a></li>
<li class="training"><a href="index.php?training"><h1>training </h1></a></li>
<li class="courses"><a href="index.php?courses"><h1>courses</h1></a></li>
<li class="register"><a href="index.php?contact"><h1>contact</h1></a></li>
</ul>
```

i just tried this myself and it worked perfectly

Comment: no luck is it because they are li? i tried switching the div to the li no luck

Comment: i edit the answer and it works... have you included the jquery library?

Comment: still had problems with it, had the jquery library, went with the straight css